# How to debug open file descriptors for deleted files?

Tags: java, file, file-descriptor

I am not getting a too many files open error, but a lot of files which are deleted still have the file descriptors.How do I debug this issue?

```
java   31386 31936    1091r      REG               202,1     96084      29253 /tmp/2810759758739832151.ttf (deleted)
java      31386 31936   1092r      REG              202,1    134200      29296 /tmp/1048743693113440284.ttf (deleted)
```

Comment: This is the traditional, standard and common way of ensuring temporary files are reliably cleaned up in Unix. Why do you think it needs to be debugged?

Comment: we have about 160,000 of these file descriptors marked deleted in production.If there are open file descriptors then they still may be occupying disk space?

Comment: If data was written to such a file -- and usually it is -- then it takes space on the filesystem containing `/tmp` but whether that filesystem is on disk depends on your system -- some systems put tmpfs in RAM for efficiency. Although some systems put it in RAM but allow swapout of the RAM to disk, so then it's using disk space after all.